# Questions about sample code from Python docs

Tags: python

This code is presented as an example in the [docs for the Python `secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html):

```
import string
import secrets
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
while True:
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(10))
if (any(c.islower() for c in password)
        and any(c.isupper() for c in password)
        and sum(c.isdigit() for c in password) >= 3):
    break
```

**Questions**

1. Where do the `c.islower()`, `c.isdigit()` and `c.isupper()` in the `if` statement came from?
2. Where did the `i` in the `password` variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a few lines and a lot of comments to walk you through it.

```py
import string # import of the string library, used for the conditions and .join function
import secrets # Import the secrets library used for password generation

# Fetch all upper and lower case numbers in the alphabet and all numbers 0-9
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
print(alphabet) # Just showing you the results

# Keep running this loop until the condition is met (I'll explain the condition below)
while True:
    # Generate a random password with the length of 10 using random characters from 'alphabet' above
    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(10))
    # the ''.join part, turns an array e.g ['a','4','Q'] into a string e.g. 'a4Q'

    # The condition part. So this script will run infinitely until the password contains:
    if (any(c.islower() for c in password) # A lower case character AND
            and any(c.isupper() for c in password) # An uppercase character AND
            and sum(c.isdigit() for c in password) >= 3): # Has a digit (aka 0-9 character)
        break # If all three of these conditions are met, then break the loop

# Print out of the resulting password
print(password)
```

The `c` represents a character in the `password` string.

`i` is the index in a range from 0 to 10. So it will go through the values from 0 to 10, [0,1...,8,9]. This means the random character generation happens 10 times and therefore gives you a password with the length of 10 characters. Note `i` never equals 10 in this situation, because 0 to 9 is 10 digits.